# transform geometry_msgs::TransformStamped to tf2::Transform transform

Tags: ros, transform, ros-indigo, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, there:

I use tf2 get a transform between two frames, with type of geometry_msgs::TransformStamped.

> ```
>   transformStamped = tf2_listener.lookupTransform(target_frame,  input.header.frame_id, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(1.0));
> ```

Now I wanna transfer the transformStamped to follow data type:

> ```
>   tf2::Transform
> ```

so that I can get OpenGL SubMatrix by

> ```
>      double mv[12];
>      *.getBasis().getOpenGLSubMatrix(mv);
> ```

How can I deal with this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280781/transform-geometry_msgs::transformstamped-to-tf2::transform-transform/) by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are the `toMsg` and `fromMsg` conversion functions in `tf2_geometry_msgs` ([API Doc](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2_geometry_msgs/html/c++/namespacetf2.html#acdf8a51ba1499cc5e9a5f4d36ad59eb5)).
Note that you'll end up with a `Stamped` transform than. But the rest is trivial...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is for ros2 bouncy but mostly similar to older versions, also using glm instead of raw arrays:

```
 glm::mat4 model_matrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
 try {
    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped tf;
    tf = tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(frame_id_, child_frame_id, tf2::TimePointZero);
    tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform> stamped_transform;
    tf2::fromMsg(tf, stamped_transform);
    #if 0
    tf2::TimePoint time_out;
    // this is private, so doesn't work 
    tf_buffer_->lookupTransformImpl(frame_id_, child_frame_id,
        tf2::TimePointZero, transform, time_out);
    #endif

    glm::dmat4 model_matrix_double;
    stamped_transform.getOpenGLMatrix(&model_matrix_double[0][0]);
    // TODO(lucasw) is there a glm double to float conversion function?
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        model_matrix[i][j] = model_matrix_double[i][j];
  } catch (tf2::TransformException& ex) {
    ...
  }
```

https://github.com/lucasw/imgui_ros/blob/406ff011234762f34027649da7e834d0a0ada6ea/imgui_ros/src/viz3d.cpp#L384

[Inside the code for lookupTransform()](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/6a46333c1510a0c7d0d108b6b2ecef5945d5a601/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp#L596) is the private lookupTransform which uses a tf2::Stamped, which is then converted to a geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped (manually, it isn't using toMsg itself) which then has to be converted immediately back in user code because API (I think tf1 exposed a tf::transform lookup, it wasn't private then)- seems inefficient but probably not too bad unless millions of these are being done in tight loop.

```
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped 
  BufferCore::lookupTransform(const std::string& target_frame, const std::string& source_frame,
      const TimePoint& time) const
{
  tf2::Transform transform;
  TimePoint time_out;
  lookupTransformImpl(target_frame, source_frame, time, transform, time_out);
  geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped msg;
  msg.transform.translation.x = transform.getOrigin().x();
  msg.transform.translation.y = transform.getOrigin().y();
  msg.transform.translation.z = transform.getOrigin().z();
  msg.transform.rotation.x = transform.getRotation().x();
  msg.transform.rotation.y = transform.getRotation().y();
  msg.transform.rotation.z = transform.getRotation().z();
  msg.transform.rotation.w = transform.getRotation().w();
  ...
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1